# Getting errors NDSolve::nlnum, NDSolve::icfail)

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I would like to plot the function `v[r]`, and resolve this differential equation in spherical simmetry:

```
ClearAll[v, r, a, b, ϵ]

ode1 = {v'[r] == v[r]* ({2 a^2/r} - {b/{r^2}})/({{v[r]}^2 - a^2}), v[ϵ] == ϵ};

With[{a = 10^22, b = 10^6}, 
  Block[{ϵ = $MachineEpsilon}, 
    sol = NDSolve[ode1, v[r], {r, .1, 10^50}, SolveDelayed -> True]]];

Plot[Evaluate[v[r] \.sol], {r, .1, 10^50}, PlotRange -> All]
```

and the out is:

> NDSolve::nlnum: The function value {{{0. -(2.22045*10^-16 (9.0072*10^15 Power[<<2>>]-2.02824*10^31 b))/(4.93038*10^-32+Times[<<2>>])}}} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {r,v[r],(v^′)[r]} = {2.22045*10^-16,2.22045*10^-16,0.}

and

> NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions

I've looked for the errors and then I've tried to rewrite the equation, but the output is still like above.

Comment: Do not use `{` and `}` in place of parentheses.  They have different meanings.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes,you're right but the errors remain the same

Comment: `b` is undefined...Use `Block` instead of `With`, maybe.  (You can see the symbol `b` in the error message.)  -- Consider what happens here: `foo = b; With[{b = 1}, foo]`

Comment: Also, you can use `DSolve` instead of `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your expression let's change the inner curly brackets

```
ode1 = {v'[r] == v[r]*({2 a^2/r} - {b/{r^2}})/({{v[r]}^2 - a^2}), v[ϵ] == ϵ};
```

to parenthesize

```
ode1 = {v'[r] == v[r]*((2 a^2/r) - (b/(r^2)))/(((v[r])^2 - a^2)), v[ϵ] == ϵ}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are more parenthesis present than needed. For example, `Power` binds more tightly than `Times`. So it could be simplified a bit to:

```
ode1 = {v'[r] == v[r]*(2 a^2/r - b/r^2)/(v[r]^2 - a^2), v[ϵ] == ϵ}
```

I think it is possible to use `Block` to achieve the result but I'm simply going to create a new equation and substitute in the numerical values you selected.

```
ode2 = ode1 /. {a -> 10^22, b -> 10^6, ϵ -> $MachineEpsilon}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now execute `NDsolve`.

```
sol = NDSolve[ode2, v[r], {r, .1, 10^50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You had a small mistake in your plot. You used `\.` when it should have been `/.`

I found the plot uninteresting over the entire range (I leave it to you) but near the origin:

```
Plot[v[r] /. sol, {r, 0.1, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note that the near-the-origin plot is still basically 0 throughout. Everything's of the order $10^{-31}$.

Comment: @bbgodfrey : It is too slow to resolve the equation through `DSolve` ! @Jack LaVigne : I would to plot the same differential equation but with the following variables and axes: `x= s= r/10^10`, `y=z(r)=v(r)/10` .Furthermore is there a kind of "time-shortcut" to resolve it through `DSolve` ?